# What are the parameters of Definition environment?

Tags: formatting, amsthm

I'm trying to redefine Definition theoremstyle and I'm stuck trying to find a single webpage where I could look up the parameters of that style. I keep finding plain style, but that's not what I want. Help.

Answer (score 6):

the `definition` environment (lowercase; i'm not familiar with `Definition`) is one of three theorem-class environments (styles) defined by `amsthm.sty`.  you should be able to find the parameters there, or `texdoc amsthm`to look at the user's guide.

`amsthm` also has a `\newtheoremstyle` facility, with which you can "roll your own".
this is also described in the `amsthm` user's guide.

to view the documented source (in `amsclass.dtx`). the "human readable" version is `amsclass.pdf`, which can be accessed by `texdoc amsclass`.

Comment: More properly, `definition` is a theorem style defined by `amsthm`.

Comment: @egreg -- thanks.  (i'm wrapped up in preparing knuth's periodic bug review, and not thinking straight.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: what is knuth's periodic bug review? Isn't it all about TeX being bug-free?

Comment: @Dror -- take a look at knuth's web page for [computers & typesetting](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/abcde.html), under "errata". it gives the schedule of the periodic review.  just because there are very few (and ever more and more obscure) bugs or glitches doesn't mean that people don't still think they have found something, so the task of evaluating and pre-sorting the collection actually entails quite a bit of correspondence and editing, so that what gets delivered is "minimum (non)working examples".